# Reshaping image data in Keras to match CNN requirements

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I've created a CNN designed to recognize objects.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

img = load_img('newimage.jpg')
x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape( (1,) + x.shape )
scores = model.predict(x, verbose=1)
print(scores)
```

However I'm getting:

```
expected convolution2d_input_1 to have shape (None, 3, 108, 192) but got array with shape (1, 3, 192, 108)
```

My model:

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, img_width, img_height)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I've looked at related answers and the documentation, but at a loss as to how to reshape the array to match what's expected?

Comment: Can you show your `model` definition?

Comment: Sure @WasiAhmad, added

Comment: I have checked your code and it worked! see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with setting up the image width and height. As the error says:

```
expected convolution2d_input_1 to have shape (None, 3, 108, 192) # expected width = 108 and height = 192 
but got array with shape (1, 3, 192, 108) # width = 192, height = 108
```

> Update: I tested your code with a small change and it worked!

I am giving just changed lines:

```
img_width, img_height = 960, 717
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)))
```

This is the main change - `input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)`

The image i used to run this code was of `width = 960` and `height = 717`. I have updated my previous answer as some part of the answer was wrong! Sorry for that.